# Migrating Kettle file repository into Kettle DB repository

Tags: repository, pentaho, kettle, migrate

Is it possible to migrate a Kettle file based repository (including history of all files) into a Kettle database repository?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just open all the file (all together or one by one), and save them (all together or one by one) in the repository.

You will loose however all the versioning (maybe that is what you call file history), unless you have the enterprise edition.

If you are wit a the community version, I suggest you use the database repository for the current version, and keep a one a week or so, export it to a file repository.